# comverting the numpy array to proper dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have numpy array as data below

```
data = np.array([[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]])
```

i want to split it and change to dataframe with column name as below to get the first value of each array as below

df_main:

```
value_items excluded_items
1 2
4 5
7 8
```

from which later I can take like

df:

```
value_items
1
4
7
```

df2:

```
excluded_items
2
5
8
```

I tried to convert to dataframe with command

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

it resulted in still array of int32

so, the splitting is failure for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reshape` for `2d array` and also add columns parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1,2), columns=['value_items','excluded_items'])
```

**Sample**:

```
data = np.arange(785*2).reshape(1, 785, 2)
print (data)
[[[   0    1]
  [   2    3]
  [   4    5]
  ...
  [1564 1565]
  [1566 1567]
  [1568 1569]]]

print (data.shape)
(1, 785, 2)

df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1,2), columns=['value_items','excluded_items'])
print (df)
     value_items  excluded_items
0              0               1
1              2               3
2              4               5
3              6               7
4              8               9
..           ...             ...
780         1560            1561
781         1562            1563
782         1564            1565
783         1566            1567
784         1568            1569

[785 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: error with shape as :     ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 785, 2)

Comment: @ML85 - I think `reshape` is necessary, edited answer.